# saving blob to image files in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an image in my database saved as a large BLOB. and now I want to retrieve it and save it to my file system.

for this purpose I have done the following, but the images that were saved to my file system were corrupted ones.

Approach1:

```
$basedir = 'images/';
$imagename = strtolower(preg_replace('/([^\w\d\-_]+)/', '-', $row->name));
$filename = $basedir . $imagename . '_' . $row->id. '.jpg';
$file_content = base64_decode($row->image_data);
return file_put_contents($filename, $file_content);
```

Approach2:

```
$basedir = 'images/';
$imagename = strtolower(preg_replace('/([^\w\d\-_]+)/', '-', $row->name));
$filename = $basedir . $imagename . '_' . $row->id . '.jpg';
fopen($filename,'w');
if($fh = fopen("{$filename}", "wb")) {
    fwrite($fh, base64_decode($row->image_data));
    fclose($fh) ;
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Why is data in a BLOB stored as base64 encoded? The point of BLOB is to store binary data, and the point of base64 is to convert binary data to plain text so it could, for example, be stored in a VARCHAR.

Comment: Yeah base64 will utilize more resources (Memory, Processing).

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick if the BLOB isn't encoded:

```
file_put_contents('filename.jpg', $row->image_data);
```

Comment: this is still saving an corrupted image .. BLOB wasnt encoded in my case